# Can't get active selector to work

Tags: css, css-selectors, hover

I've set up a gallery type page using the following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/g2hY4/

I'd like to change the small thumbnail image opacity to 1 while the thumbnail is active (as is the case when you hover over the thumbnail). I have tried adding some CSS like this...

```
 #One:active {
     opacity: 1;
 }
```

But that isn't working.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Which browser?  All browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an *active* selector supported for images in css. Why not set the opacity in the Javascript?

You can set the opacity of your image in your displayImage function with `this.style.opacity=1;`.

Of course you would also need to reset the opacity of the previous thumbnails so they won't keep opacity 1:

```
var thumbnails = document.getElementById("thumbnails").getElementsByTagName("img");
for (i=0; i<thumbnails.length; i++)
    thumbnails[i].style.opacity=null;
```

Create a div with the id "thumbnails" around the thumbnails for that to work.

I have created an update here http://jsfiddle.net/g2hY4/2/.